# What's the best way to add a delay and transition of overlay DIV being shown?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm not really any good at JS, so please bear with me.

I've got this portion of code that makes an overlay appear over the site when the menu is hovered over.

```
$('#menu-main-menu > .menu-parent-item').hover(
    // when hovered
        function() {
            $('#overlay').css('display','block');
        },
    // when NOT hovered
        function() {
            $('#overlay').css('display','none');
        }
);
```

The overlay div is shown instantly when the mouse hovers over the menu. The menu items themselves have a nice CSS fade as they come in, but I'd like to apply either a smooth transition, or a delay to the overlay div.

Can something like be easily added to this code, or would that be better being performed by CSS transition also?

Answer (score 3):

Use [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)/[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) with `duration` like

```
$('#menu-main-menu > .menu-parent-item').hover(
    // when hovered
        function() {
            $('#overlay').fadeIn(1000);
        },
    // when NOT hovered
        function() {
            $('#overlay').fadeOut(1000);
        }
);
```

Alternately, you can use [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) with `duration` to maintain `display:block/none`

```
$('#menu-main-menu > .menu-parent-item').hover(
    // when hovered
        function() {
            $('#overlay').show(1000);
        },
    // when NOT hovered
        function() {
            $('#overlay').hide(1000);
        }
);
```

Comment: This is good and simple, although when passing from one menu item to the other, the overlay is fading out and then in again, where as it should ideally stay visible, until the mouse is off the entire menu. If you could just change the target, to just the menu, that would be fine!

Comment: @Lee, can you show some more code or a fiddle so I can help?

Comment: Hmm I meant the first line. I get the desired behaviour when I remove `> .menu-parent-item` and just target the menu container. Also just to let you know, when I try the show/hide with delay times, it doesn't fade.. it swipes in from the left.

Comment: @Lee, for show/hide, I believe if you pass in an `easing` variable, you can control the direction

Comment: Actually, no I can't just use the menu container, as I don't wnat to target every menu item, only those with children items.

Comment: @Lee, then try `$('#menu-main-menu:has(.menu-parent-item)')`

Comment: No, that's still doing the same behaviour, because of course the menu does contain parent items, so the hide and show will still happen for all menu items.

Comment: @Lee, replicate it in a fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeOut should allow the delay

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    //your code 
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: Should this wrap around the entire code I pasted above? Or does 'your code' apply to the two css(display) parts?